# Discord.js Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot and i keep getting an error.

I got the code off of this website - https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin

When I do Node deploy-commands in the terminal and error pops up saying this -

```
Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory, scandir 'C:\Users\family\OneDrive\CipherBot\commands\test.js'
    at Object.readdirSync (node:fs:1452:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\family\OneDrive\CipherBot\deploy-commands.js:14:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  errno: -4052,
  syscall: 'scandir',
  code: 'ENOTDIR',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\family\\OneDrive\\CipherBot\\commands\\test.js'
}
```

I do not know what this error means and have never seen it before

Below is index code for the bot

```js
    const fs = require('node:fs');
    const path = require('node:path');
    const { Client, Collection, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
    const { token } = require('./config.json');

    const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });

    client.commands = new Collection();
    const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
    const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

    for (const folder of commandFolders) {
        const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
        const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for (const file of commandFiles) {
            const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
            const command = require(filePath);
            if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
                client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
            } else {
                console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
            }
        }
    }

    client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
        console.log('Ready!');
    });

    client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
        if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

        const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

        if (!command) return;

        try {
            await command.execute(interaction);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
                await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
            } else {
                await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
            }
        }
    });

    client.login(token);
```

Deploy Commands to send the commands to the Discord bot -

```
const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');

const commands = [];
// Grab all the command folders from the commands directory you created earlier
const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    // Grab all the command files from the commands directory you created earlier
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    // Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
    }
}

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

// and deploy your commands!
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Test Command that i am trying to send -

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('ping')
        .setDescription('Replies with Pong!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Pong!');
    },
};
```

Files -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BBch.png)

I tryed to change around the files and that is about all i could think of that would fix it

Comment: Please, please don't post your code and errors as images.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create another folder in the `commands` folder and move the test.js file to the new folder.

Your file system will be:

```
Workspace
  - commands
    - test
      - test.js
```

If you don't understand what I meant then check this image, it has the file system you need.

Your file system:

[image: Your Current File System]

It should be:

[image: Correct File System]

Comment: I did that and then it gave me a different error. it said something about an invalid form body and that value "undefined" is not snowflake (?)

Comment: @OverlordShado Then it is something with the command